# Only writing first row to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape page. I can get it to pull all the data and save it to array objects but cannot get my for loop to iterate over every index of the arrays and output those to CSV. It will write the headers and the first object. Novice to writing code so any help is appreciated.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/air-force/'

# Open Connection & Grabbing the Page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

#Creating variable to Save the Page
page_html = uClient.read()

#Closing the connection
uClient.close()

#Parse the data to HTML
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Grab container info from the DOM
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"overthrow table_container"})

filename = "airforce.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "year, wins, losses, ties, wl, sos\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
 #Find all years
 year_container = container.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"year_id"})
 year = year_container[0].text

 #Find number of Wins
 wins_container = container.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"wins"})
 wins = wins_container[0].text

 #Find number of Wins
 losses_container = container.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"losses"})
 losses = losses_container[0].text

 #Number of Ties if any
 ties_container = container.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"ties"})
 ties = ties_container[0].text

 #Win-Loss as a percentage
 wl_container = container.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"win_loss_pct"})
 wl = wl_container[0].text


 #Strength of Schedule. Can be +/- w/0 being average
 sos_container = container.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"sos"})
 sos = sos_container[0].text

 f.write(year + "," + wins + "," + losses + "," + ties + "," + wl + "," + 
 sos + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: have you checked how many containers you had? and is indentation correct? check that. Try to print `len(list(containers))`

Comment: for instance it can happen if `f.write(year + "," + wins + "," + losses + "," + ties + "," + wl + "," + 
 sos + "\n")` is unindented (outside the loop). the current indentation is 1 space which is uncommon and error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed the indentation and it had no change. It does look like their is only one container on the page so that would make since why its not iterating through like i thought. Any thoughts on how i could fix the for loop to iterated over the remaining objects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pulling up the html source code, there is only one container to be put into your container list.  Which means that your `for` loop is trying to access the wrong information.

You should use a `range()` generator to access the different elements of `td` that reside inside of the one item in your `containers` list.

try this

```
#number of records to iterate over
num = len(list(containers.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"year_id"})))

for i in range(num):
    #Find all years
    year_container = containers.findAll("td",{"data-stat":"year_id"})
    year = year_containers[i].text
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I was able to get the data i needed.

Comment: @EricBaker Great to hear.  And welcome to the community. If an answer has helped you solve your problem, you should accept it. See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: It might work but is _horribly inefficient_ to search for all year containers over and over again to just pluck _one_ of them at each iteration. Also iterating over index values is unpythonic when you can iterate over the elements directly instead.  A simple `for year_container in containers.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'year_id'}): year = year_container.text` could replace all of it.

Comment: @BlackJack Really?  And that will pull all the data the OP wanted? I think not.  He is grabbing multiple data points form each iteration.  Perhaps there is a more appropriate way to solve it but don;t come down vote me and then lie about how well you could solve it.

Comment: @jk622 The code does exactly what your code does, just in a straight forward, simpler, and pythonic way. If that's not what the OP wants that's also a reason to downvote. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the table (body) and then iterate over the table rows that are not header rows, i.e. all rows that don't have a class.

For writing (and reading) CSV files there is a `csv` module in the standard library.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen

import bs4


def iter_rows(html):
    headers = ['year_id', 'wins', 'losses', 'ties', 'win_loss_pct', 'sos']
    yield headers

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table_body_node = soup.find('table', 'stats_table').tbody
    for row_node in table_body_node('tr'):
        if not row_node.get('class'):
            yield [
                row_node.find('td', {'data-stat': header}).text
                for header in headers
            ]


def main():
    url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/schools/air-force/'
    with urlopen(url) as response:
        html = response.read()

    with open('airforce.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        csv.writer(csv_file).writerows(iter_rows(html))   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```